# create javascript new operator dynamically

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have two functions `nameFuncOne` and `nameFuncTwo` that i represented in my code.

```
this.mainFunction = function() {
    this.someFunc = function() {
    return this.name;
  }
};

this.nameFuncOne = function() {
    this.name = "nameOne";
    mainFunction.call(this);
};
this.nameFuncTwo = function() {
    this.name = "nameTwo";
    mainFunction.call(this);
};
var one = new nameFuncOne();
var two = new nameFuncTwo();
console.log(one.someFunc() + "  " + two.someFunc());
```

so here what i did is assigning constructor functions **nameFuncOne** and **nameFuncTwo** into the variables `one` and `two`. so why i cant create something like this.

```
var funcArr = ["new nameFuncOne()", "new nameFuncTwo()"];
var arr = [];
for (var i=0;i<funcArr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = funcArr[i];
  //console.log(arr[i].someFunc())
}
```

my question is i dont want to create variables manually. is there any way to do this. please correct me if i went wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Comment: No this doesnt solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

yes yo can do like that, but there is problem in your code. you store `string` into array.

try this,

```
var funcArr = ["new nameFuncOne()", "new nameFuncTwo()"];
var arr = [];
for (var i=0;i<funcArr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = eval(funcArr[i]);
     console.log(arr[i].someFunc())
}
```

The eval() function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string. [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

another way:

```
var funcArr = [new nameFuncOne(), new nameFuncTwo()];
    var arr = [];
    for (var i=0;i<funcArr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = funcArr[i];
         console.log(arr[i].someFunc())
    }
```

Comment: yes eval is bad idea,it opens up your code for injection attacks. but you store string in array so you have to execute it.